# Name for a matrix with sum of elements along every row/column is equal?

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

Is there a specific name for a symmetric matrix where sum of elements along every individual row is equal to the sum of elements along every individual column?

For example,

\begin{equation*}
A = \begin{bmatrix}
x & 0 & y \\
0 & x & y \\
y & y & x
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

is symmetric matrix but the sum of elements along the rows 1,2,3, respectively is $x+y$, $x+y$ and $2y+x$.

However,

\begin{equation*}
B = \begin{bmatrix}
x & y & y \\
y & x & y \\
y & y & x
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

is also symmetric, while the sum of all elements along rows/cols is $2y+x$.

Thanks!

Comment: If all elements are non-negative, then it is a scalar multiple of a symmetric [doubly stochastic matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_stochastic_matrix).

Comment: Thank you! And is there any proof/document describing the eigenvectors of these matrices? Is there any general rule with regards to these?
It is clear that $v=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \dots 1 \end{bmatrix}$ is an eigenvector, but what happens with the other n-1 vectors?

Comment: You can’t say anything about the other eigenvectors, only that thei live in hyperplane orthogonal to [1,1,...,1].